# worklight send push notification for all subscribed users

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have to schedule a downtime in order to do some stuff on the production server. My customer wants me to send a push notification to all the subscribed users in order to notify them by the downtime.

Is that possible? If I want to do it even by code will it be possible?
I'm on worklight 6.0.0.0

Answer (score 5):

Using the Worklight Console you can notify the users of your application taking advantage of the "Active, Notifying" setting. This will allow you to display a notification message on startup telling the customer of scheduled downtime. Even when the downtime occurs you can use the same mechanism and set the application to "disabled" with a notification message stating the application is currently down. Please look at the following documentation for more information:

**Displaying a notification message on application startup**:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_displaying_a_notification_message_on_app_startup.html

**Defining administrator messages from Worklight Console in multiple languages:**
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_defining_multi-language_admin_notifications.html

Comment: Yeah I know, this is going to notify only the users that will open the application (specifically invoke /init request). But I'd like to have a real push message sent to all users.

Comment: Isn't this the expected behavior you want though? If a user opens the application before the downtime occurs you can make them aware of the upcoming maintenance. If the user opens the application when the downtime is occurring a notification can also be displayed and the application can be disabled. If you really want a notification sent to all users it is going to take some additional coding as you would have to loop through all your subscribed users and use the following API:

WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notificationOptions)

Comment: yes but how to loop on all the user subscriptions that was originally my question. Any way thanks for the notification trick I used it yesterday :-)

Comment: I still believe the above notification mechanism will be the easiest solution to implement and fastest performance wise. If you still wish to send push to all users you will have to write some code to get the eventSource and then send a notification to all of its users. Have a look at the following

[Push Sample.](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf) 

Can you please mark the question as answered if the information you requested has been provided

Comment: Yes technically it's not the same concept. I cannot mark it as answered because it doesn't respond to my exact need. But I would be happy to up vote it ;)

Comment: I also get same requestion, customer company want to send messages to all of its clients, but the sender is not IT staff and cannot access Worklight console, they expect we show a desktop web page for this function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Wl.Server.sendMessage, you just need to send the applicationId and notificationOptions where you can pass only the message to send and this method will be send to all users, of if you want you can pass  a kind of target for specify the users

I hope this help you

For more info check these links:
Tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/tag-based-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/

Documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/es/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#sendMessage